# Ionic 3 /Angular dropdown select value from nested array object

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I get response from an API that incorporates, nested array of objects in the following way.

```
var virtualAddrObjFinal = [
    {
      "accountNo": "5019000",
      "vpainfo": [
        {
          "vpa": "newq@bandhan"
        },
        {
          "vpa": "log@bandhan"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "accountNo": "1018000",
      "vpainfo": [
        {
          "vpa": "newesaf@bandhan"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

And want to populate the values in dropdown using `vpainfo` object. Here am having issue with the nested object. Can any one suggest the way to achieve this.

I have tried the below way,

```
<ion-select [formControl]="vaddr" (ionChange)="fetchVPAAccountNumber($event)" interface="popover">
   <ion-option *ngFor="let vaddrlist of virtualAddrObjFinal.vpainfo;let i = index" [value]="vaddrlist">{{vaddrlist.vpa}}
   </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

And need to show the `accountNo` after selecting the specific `vpa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-form-control-gpzsez?file=pages/home/home.ts) so that you can check my solution.

**HTML** - In your html, you need to add ng-container to hold the first `ngFor` to iterate the `virtualAddrObjFinal` array then add the second `ngFor`in your ion-option to iterate the list of vpainfo. I also added a label for the selected account number that will only show when you only selected something from the ion-select.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-select style="width: 100%" formControlName="vaddr" (ionChange)="fetchVPAAccountNumber($event)" interface="popover">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of virtualAddrObjFinal;let i = index">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let vaddrlist of item.vpainfo;let i = index" [value]="vaddrlist">{{vaddrlist.vpa}}
      </ion-option>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
<ion-item *ngIf="form.controls['vaddr'].value">
  <ion-label>Account Number: {{accountNumber}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

**TS** - In the ts file, I filtered the `virtualAddrObjFinal` array which checks the correct accountNumber for the selected vpa from the `ion-select`. Then, I assigned it to the `accountNumber` variable.

```
fetchVPAAccountNumber(ev) {
  const selected = this.virtualAddrObjFinal.filter((e) => {
    return e.vpainfo.some((v) => {
      return v.vpa.indexOf(ev.vpa) > -1;
    });
  });
  this.accountNumber = selected.length > 0 ? selected[0].accountNo : '';
}
```

Comment: Great! it is working fine